# Proving this set $A$ is closed for the $d_{\infty}$ metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $C([0,1])$ be the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $d_{\infty} = \sup \left\{ | f(t) - g(t) | \mid t \in [0,1] \right\}$ be a metric.

I need to prove that the set $$A = \left\{ f \in C([0,1]) \mid \forall t \in [0,1] : f(t) \geq 0 \right\} $$ is closed for this metric.

**Attempt:** I tried using the sequence approach, by showing the limit is in $A$. So let $(f_n)_n \in A$ be a convergent sequence of functions such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = f$ for the $d_{\infty}$ metric, with $f \in C([0,1])$. I want to prove that $f \in A$. We know that $(f_n(t)) \geq 0 $ for all $t \in [0,1]$, but I'm not sure how to conclude from this that $f(t) \geq 0$.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If $f_n\to f$ under this metric then also $f_n(t)\to f(t)$ for each $t$.

Comment: I know that. But that doesn't show that $f(t) \geq 0$ ?

Comment: It does if $f_n(t)\to f(t)$ and secondly $f_n(t)\geq0$ for each $n$. This because $[0,\infty)$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n \to f$ in the $d_\infty$ metric then in particular $f_n(t) \to f(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. If $f_n(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$ and $f_n(t) \to f(t)$ then $f(t) \ge 0$ by elementary order properties of limits.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For a fixed $t\in[0,1]$ we have $|f(t)-g(t)|\leq d_{\infty}(f,g)$ so that convergence w.r.t. $d_{\infty}$ implies with pointwise convergence.